# Linq to Entities - insert all objects with TagID in string[] into an ICollection<Tag>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

Tag object

```
  public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
```

I have an `ICollection<Tag>` - and a `string[]` with `TagID`'s in. How can I insert `Tag` objects into the `ICollection<Tag>` corresponding to the `TagID`'s in the `string[]` array?

I would like to do this in one Linq statement (rather than a loop).

Comment: So, got got a list of TagIDs and an empty collection of Tag objects you want to fill. Where do you get the values for `Name` and `NamePlural` from?

Comment: Lets say there are already 5 tags, with ID's 1-5 (each has a Name and NamePlural). I have a string[] with say, ID's 1, 3, 5 in - I'd like to populate an ICollection<Tag> - with 3 tags, the ones with ID's 1, 3, 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the TagObjects that have a matching id in your string array, so you can use `Where()` and `Contains()`:

```
ICollection<TagObject> collection;
string[] ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
collection = source.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.TagID.ToString())).ToList();
```

Every item in your `TagObject` source will be evaluated using the `ids.Contains(t.TagID.ToString())` expression.  If the `TagObject` id has a match the `ids` array, this expression will return `true`, causing the `TagObject` that has been evaluated to be included in the results of `Where()`.

**EDIT**

As it's Linq to Entities, the simple way to get around the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Would be to convert your ids array to ints beforehand:

```
ICollection<TagObject> collection;
string[] ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
int[] convertedIds = ids.Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToArray();
collection = source.Where(t => convertedIds.Contains(t.TagID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - could you briefly explain what's happening?

Comment: I have added an explanation, let me know if this isn't clear and I'll re-word it!

Comment: thanks - it's returning this error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: In which case it's not Linq to Objects (as title states).  Convert the string[] ids array to ints using ids.Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)) beforehand and then remove the .ToString() from t.TagID.ToString().

Comment: sorry could you paste the whole statement please

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>() {new Tag() {TagID = "tag1"}, new Tag() {TagID = "tag4"}, new Tag() {TagID = "tag3"}};
        string[] tagIds = new[] {"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"};

        IEnumerable<Tag> result = tags.Where(tag => tagIds.Contains(tag.TagID));
    }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - getting error: "string[] does not contain a definition for Contains"

Comment: also it is TagID - not Name (FYI, not sure if this would matter)

Comment: No it doesn't change anything but I renamed the field even so

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need :

```
string[] tagIds = new string[] {"1",  ...};

ICollection<Tag> result = tagList.Where(tag => tagIds.Contains<string>(tag.TagID.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: for each `tag` in the list I'm checking if it exist in the `tagIds`. Also you may want ot read about lambada expressions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx